# Connecting and managing on-prem Windows Server from Azure

Tags: azure, windows-server-2019

Is there a way to manage my on-prem Windows Server 2019 from Azure so I am able to for example create Azure VMs on it using Azure CLI (az.exe)?

My intention is to reuse unused on-prem hardware for testing purposes while having Azure class management capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bring on-prem machines into Azure for management using [Azure Arc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/azure-arc). However, this will not let you run Azure VMs on on-prem machines.

[Azure Stack](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/azure-stack/) can run Azure VMs on on-prem hardware, but it requires specific hardware and is costly. Given the cost of this, if you do not need the other features, it is going to be cheaper just to run your test workloads in Azure.

Comment: That is what I also concluded. Thank you for the answer!